# Validation issues in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise

I'm using Rails 3.2.16, devise and mongoid (possible relevant Gems for this question).

After a user signs up I have devise redirect them them to create a new profile, which `belongs_to :user`. I'm doing this with the following devise override:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_profile_path
  end
```

On the profile, I'm calling validation in various places, for example `validates :biz_name, :on => :update, :presence => {:message => 'Business name cannot be blank'}`.

When the `new_profile_path` loads after the user signs up they immediately get validation errors on the fields that I've called validation for. I was stumped at first because per my code above, I'm calling validation on `update` only. So it didn't make sense why validation was running.

Anyhow, I tracked down my error. I have a few fields in my profile model that have defaults on them, such as `field :position_order,    :type => Integer, :default => 1`. It seems as though the profile is created with these default values first, then when shown to the user to edit, it's actually the `update` method getting called - thus the validation errors getting called.

How do I fix this? At the end of the day, I want two things:

-Populate the profile with some default values before the user is able to edit their profile
-On the first view of the profile edit page, validation should not run (so the user doesn't see a bunch of errors before they have even done anything).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I would say you should rethink the requirements. What use have invalid default values?

And you also can supply frontend behaviour to guide the user to correct input with HTML or Javascript.

Comment: Re: suggest #2, I can but i want server side validation too so I don't want to just rely on client side validation. Re: #1 I'm open to rethinking the requirements but I'm not sure how to accomplish it. I need default values for example, depending on the account type the user registers at it gives the profile a "position value". For example, if account level = pro the position value might be 1 vs if account level = intermediate the position value might be 2. That's why I'm using defaults. I *guess* i can use hidden fields not the profile edit but I'm not sure that's the best way?

Comment: I just meant it should work if the defaults you use are valid in your validations scenarios. And yes there is even client side validation :) . I just meant the placeholder in form fields or a tool tip via mouse over or something. So in your example I would just add a biz_name default. I don't say that would be the best solution. Maybe somebody else has a good hint.

Comment: Not all the fields that needs to be validated have defaults - that's where I run into the problem. Thanks for the responses, btw.

Comment: And you can have a look at [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) . So you have to write some logic to add the needed defaults in associated models if that are the requirements.

Comment: Maybe you take the time and give a short example that causes the problem. Two related models and one attribute that you need the default for or whatever it is. Then somebody more experienced can give a better suggestion :) .

Comment: If you request the new_profile_path directly for example, are there validation errors as well? If I am correct there shouldn't be any.

Comment: There is no way to "access it directly" as the new profile path is loaded immediately after the user signs up. For the profile to be saved the validation errors need to be fixed then saved. Thus when accessing the new_profile_path or edit_profile_path the profile is already filled of.

Comment: I meant while debugging ;). So i see the request flow like this: 1. request new_profile - there should be no validation errors 2. request create profile - there should be validation errors.

Comment: Also just add the models and attributes involved. Then it is easier to follow your requirements. Associations, one related attribute and existing callback or own set-default-methods.

Comment: Per my original question - I've debugged already. I know what that problem is - I just don't know *how* to solve it.

Comment: oki, then sorry for confusing you. Maybe I am wrong. Hopefully somebody more experienced can help. Good luck.

Comment: Did you have any success so far?

Comment: Nope, no success so far.